# How can we prove or otherwise that some of the dead rose from their tombs at the point of Jesus' death? [Mt 27:52]

Tags: jesus, resurrection, death

> When Jesus had cried out again in a loud voice, He yielded up His spirit. At that moment the veil of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom. The earth quaked and the rocks were split. The tombs broke open, and the bodies of many saints who had fallen asleep were raised. After Jesus’ resurrection, when they had come out of the tombs, they entered the holy city and appeared to many people.
> [ Mt 27:50-53 (BSB) ]

Are they any biblical or extra biblical evidence to prove that this actually happened? It is clear from the passage that these resurrected saints — resurrected even before Christ? but after the manner of Lazarus, or not? — were seen to "many people" in Jerusalem. Are there no records of such an extraordinary event, or perhaps they had paled in comparison to the other supernatural events happening all over at that time, such as the tearing of the veil, etc.

(Note: I need not say this, but it happened frequently, namely, no evidence is no proof.)

Comment: Other than the comment in Matt 27:52, I know of no other data about this event.

Comment: Thanks. Neither do I, but perhaps, someone else in this whole wide world may know. That is why I'm asking.

Comment: There might be some reference to it in the early church fathers, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/18779/matt-2752-tombs-also-were-opened-apocalyptic-symbolism