# How was the 20% tax enough to last all 7 years of famine?

Tags: genesis, joseph, mathematics

In Genesis 41, Joseph interpreted Pharoah's dreams as predicting 7 years of plenty followed by 7 years of famine. In verse 34, he recommends a 20% tax on grain during the good years to provide food during the "bad" years:

> Let Pharaoh appoint commissioners over the land to take a fifth of the harvest of Egypt during the seven years of abundance.

How was this enough to "cover" all 7 years of famine (especially given the fact that they were evidently supplying grain to other parts of the Ancient Near East, given that Joseph's brothers eventually went there to get grain)? Also, if the grain was stored, the grain would've needed to last a minimum of 8 years. How would they have made it last that long? Is there any possibility that they would've planted at least some of the grain that they had collected, for example?

Comment: A "year of famine" doesn't necessarily mean that **zero** food is produced. It just means that less is produced than what would be needed by the population.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fun one. Unfortunately, Genesis does not preserve the Egyptians' inventory projections for these years. But, in addition to the helpful [insights](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/75356/39862) by Dottard, the following are probable contributors:

- Egypt was a regional superpower. We don't have as much data on their agriculture as we do for more recent superpowers, but where we do have data there's a fairly stable trend: *superpowers produce more food than they eat*. It's very difficult to stay on top of the world if you are dependent on neighboring nations for your next meal (Peloponnesian War, anyone?). At the height of its power, Egypt was almost certainly a net exporter of food. Therefore, 100% output was already more than what was needed to feed the population.
- The first 7 years were years of great plenty, and there's no suggestion at all that people were asked to tighten their belts during the years of plenty--ergo, 80% of the harvest was at least as much (if not quite a bit more) than was necessary to feed Egypt's population plus trading partners.
- In times of famine animals are slaughtered in greater numbers a) because animals are a reliable long-term storage of protein that can be utilized when other sources are unavailable & b) because  if there's not enough food for the humans and the animals, the humans get priority (e.g. Shackleton's men eating their dogs). Since the grain would feed humans and animals, as the animal population shrank over the 7 years, the total Egyptian consumption of grain would go down each year.
- Total food production during the famine was not zero, so there would still have been a marginal contribution to the food supply from ongoing production, slowing the rate of inventory depletion.

Grain, if kept dry, can be stored for decades. 7-8 years would present no difficulty for well-stored wheat ([source](https://theprovidentprepper.org/food-storage-how-to-store-wheat-so-it-is-still-delicious-31-years-later/#:%7E:text=Wheat%20has%20an%20incredibly%20long,against%20hunger%20during%20hard%20times.)).

Comment: We actually have scriptural witness that Egypt was exporting food: Jacob sent his sons there to buy food when the famine was in force.

Comment: @EvilSnack agree they certainly did export food during the famine. The argument in my post is that they were probably an exporter before the famine as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent question that has been asked several times before.  Here are some of the usual answers as to why only one fifth of the harvest would have been sufficient to last seven years:

Note the comments of Ellicott:

> (34) **Take up the fifth part of the land**.—Heb., let him fifth the land,
> that is, exact a fifth part of the produce. It has been supposed that
> it had been usual in Egypt to pay to the king a tithe of the crop, and
> the doubling of the impost would not press very heavily on the people
> in these years of extraordinary abundance. As the reason of the
> enactment would be made known, it would also induce all careful people
> to store up a portion of their own superabundance for future need.

Benson is more specific:

> **Let him appoint officers to take up a fifth part** — ... why only a
> fifth part, seeing the years of famine were to be as many as the years
> of plenty?
>
> - 1st, Because people would live more sparingly in the time of the famine.
> - 2d, It is likely that many persons, in all parts of the country, besides the king, would lay up great quantities of corn [= "grain" in modern English], both because
>   they could not easily consume it all, and in expectation of a time of
>   greater scarcity and dearness, when they might either use it
>   themselves, or sell it to their advantage. Add to this,
> - 3d, That even the fifth part of the produce of those years of plenty might be more than the half, yea, equal to the whole crop of
>   ordinary years.

Matthew Poole gives almost identical three reasons, as does Gill.

Comment: Corn? Never corn! Grain, yes, but corn? How did the Egyptians get corn, a plant native to Americas at that time?

Comment: @jo1storm - "corn" in the Elizabethan word for "grain" generally; hence the KJV translation.  In modern American English, the meaning of "corn" is much more restricted.

Comment: But we do not live in Elizabethan times. You might as well have used the word rice, it would be the same level of correct.

Comment: @jo1storm - you are missing the point - "corn" in England still means Grain generally; Benson is a 19th Century English commentator.  It is American English where ":corn" means "maize" as in England.  Note the translatiuon of the KJV which these commentators quote - see Gen 41:5, 35, 49, etc, use "corn"

Comment: You are missing the point. We are not in 19th century England. Corn has a different and very specific meaning today. And there was no corn in Egypt at the time being discussed. So we can say that "It is likely that many persons, in all parts of the country, besides the king, would lay up great quantities of corn" is simply false. There was no corn anywhere in Middle East/Egypt/general area. Now, if you wrote grain or food or crops, it would have been ok. Corn or maize? No. Just no. I'll accept it if you were scholar from 19th century in which case... Please tell me the secret of immortality.

Comment: @jo1storm - look at my answer - I did NOT say corn - I quoted an English commentator who said that, and when he said it, that was correct.  The KJV (which he quotes) still says it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Benson  I have added an explanatory note to help you.

Comment: I shall not take umbrage with thee if thou art wont to utter in the tongue of the dread Sovereign Elizabeth. In any event, I agree the [etymology](https://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/ingredients/article/the-etymology-of-the-word-corn) of "corn" is pretty cool. "Corn" has been used to refer to many grains, and now "grain" refers to part of the corn plant =). @jo1storm - Dottard has indeed discovered the secret of immortality--he wrote about it in [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/63790/39862).

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Indeed, but if the person asking the question used the word corn today, in class or in the street in the terms of "Egyptians grew corn" they would get in trouble. They would get mocked at the very least. And I don't like people getting in trouble and being mocked. We often forget that people don't ask questions here for the sake of asking questions.  "Yeah, I used corn in archaic meaning, in a way nobody uses the word corn in a hundred years. Because I am KJV bible aficionado."

Answer (score 0):

Even though I agree with the thought that corn may not have been there, there seems to be no proof that it was not there.  I have a friend (trained to be a minister, but chose a different field after he ministered overseas) that said that he studied and found that it was impossible for corn to grow because of all the volcanic activity in the area at that time…   The problem is there are many scriptures that have grains (including corn) listed in them.  Here is a look at how many times that certain grains showed up in the Old and New Testaments as a whole.
Old Testament:  Corn (86), Wheat (39), Rie (2), Barley (32), Flax (9)
New Testament: Corn (8), Wheat (12), (Rie 0), Barley (3), Flax (1)
Although Flax is not a grain, it can be used as a grain.
LEV 2:12 talks about corn being roasted and beaten.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).